# How to programatically get value printed by Kubernetes in --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash after using kubeadm init

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have this specific use case, in which we remotely create Kubernetes clusters on a significant number of machines. When we run `kubeadm init` at the end the join commands gets printed as:

`kubeadm join [IPv6-Address]:6443 --token TOKEN_VALUE --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash CERT_HASH`

In order to programmatically join worker nodes we have a script that needs both the `TOKEN_VALUE` and the `CERT_HASH`.

As now I'm acquiring the `TOKEN_VALUE` with the following command: `sudo kubeadm token list | awk 'NR == 2 {print $1}'`. However, I haven't found an easy way(or any way at all) to obtain the `CERT_HASH`.

Any help or pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those with the same problem, there doesn't seem to be a super clean or easy way to get it. But after looking at some places, the one that worked for me is `openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt -noout -pubkey | openssl rsa -pubin -outform DER 2>/dev/null | sha256sum | cut -d' ' -f1`

Answer (score 4):

Just run below command on control node

`kubeadm token create --print-join-command`

Refer the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-token/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using ansible to automate the join process, you can use the `x509_certificate_info` module:

```yaml
# Get cert info
- name: Get CA certificate hash
  delegate_to: "{{ groups.k8s_master }}"
  community.crypto.x509_certificate_info:
    path: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
  register: __k8s_pki_ca

# Use the info
- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: 'sha256:{{ __k8s_pki_ca["public_key_fingerprints"]["sha256"] | replace(":","") }}'
```

Using this allows to automate the join command even with the new kubeadm conf option. More about the crypto-cert module can be found in the [ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/x509_certificate_info_module.html)